# HAPROXY : Proxy tunneling failed: SSL

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy

I am using haproxy as reverse proxy for 5 domain and using SSL (haproxy termination) which convert all http  request to https. This is working fine in the browser.

But when I try to wget (only with in 5 domain which I configured through HAproxy) I am getting below error.

```
root@stg-jira:~# wget https://stg-confluence.example.com
--2016-08-04 11:13:14--  https://stg-confluence.example.com/
Resolving proxy.ebiz.example.com (proxy.ebiz.example.com)... 100.244.32.2
Connecting to proxy.ebiz.example.com (proxy.ebiz.example.com)|100.244.32.2|:80... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Service UnavailableUnable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/server tech support.

Answer (score 0):

wget require quite specyfic ssl chains. Typical ssl key and cert is not enough. Even CA cert could be not enough. I cannot chaeck what is wrong exactly in your situation because this page is down. Probably you change domain adress just for showing example.

Sorry that i don't send you more info, but I would need example to test it.